# Sanitize or trim URL and return array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, url, trim, sanitize

I want to parse a URL. This is the code I got from a tutorial, so I am assuming it is correct:

```
public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url']))
        {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
```

I am using `explode` to return an array of every section of the URL string, like this:

> Home/index/page

into

```
Array ( [0] => home [1] => index [2] => page )
```

I have read about `rtrim`, `filter_sanitize_url` and `explode`, but I don't know why the code above includes all three of them. 
Wouldn't sanitizing the string automatically trim the '/' character? Therefore, it would not be necessary to trim the '/', but only the whitespaces...(?)

In addition, if the explode delimeter is also '/',  how does it still identify where the array "starts and ends" if '/' is supposedly deleted by both trim and sanitize_url?

Is it fine if I simly omit the rtrim charlist '/'? It still works as far aas I have tried.

I'm confused, I might be mixing up concepts, a small explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Read once here then you will understand why it's used http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php  and  http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...if the explode delimeter is also '/', how does it still identify where the array "starts and ends" if '/' is supposedly deleted by both trim and sanitize_url?*

Explode can still use '/' as a delimiter because [`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) does not target '/' as a character to remove, and [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) is only removing the slashes that exist as a last character in your url. `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` has a complete list of character it strips from a string, but it really targets non-ASCII characters, and other such characters that should not belong in a url. The forward slash character does belong in a url, to designate pathing, so it is not removed here. `rtrim` does remove the forward slash character, as specified, but there's a difference between `rtrim` and removing all matching characters. `rtrim` is solely *right trim*, meaning the right most character of the input string is looked at and if a match is found based on the target character, it will be removed. As such, `explode` will still work as expected since all internal '/' characters are left intact after this filtering.